# how would I convert code from 2 dimensional array into list?

Tags: c#

I am posting yet once again and cannot seem to find an easy way to convert this. I have tried to get rid of the 2 dimensional array for this method, ExtractData and replace it with using a list but am having no luck. Would you guys be able to give me some examples or ideas I can go off of? Thank you.

```
private void ExtractData( DateTime dtmDay )
  {
     // set to selected date in MonthCalendar control
     int intChosenDay = dtmDay.Day;
     int intFileDay; // day of event from file
     int intLineNumbers; // counts lines to skip

     m_intNumberOfEvents = 0; // set number of events to 0

     // initialize StreamReader to read lines from file
     StreamReader objInput = 
        new StreamReader( "calendar.txt" );

     // read first line before entering loop
     string strLine = objInput.ReadLine();

     // loop through lines in file
     while ( objInput.Peek() > -1 &&
        m_intNumberOfEvents < 10 )
     {
        intFileDay = Int32.Parse( strLine ); // extract day

        // if event scheduled for specified day,
        // store information
        if ( intFileDay == intChosenDay )
        {
           m_strData[ m_intNumberOfEvents, 0 ] = strLine;
           m_strData[ m_intNumberOfEvents, 1 ] = 
              objInput.ReadLine();
           m_strData[ m_intNumberOfEvents, 2 ] = 
              objInput.ReadLine();
           m_strData[ m_intNumberOfEvents, 3 ] = 
              objInput.ReadLine();
           m_strData[ m_intNumberOfEvents, 4 ] = 
              objInput.ReadLine();
           m_intNumberOfEvents++;
        }
        else
        {
           // skip to next event in file
           for ( intLineNumbers = 0; intLineNumbers <= 3;
              intLineNumbers++ )
              strLine = objInput.ReadLine();
        }

        // read day of next event in file
        strLine = objInput.ReadLine();

     } // end while

  } // end method ExtractData
```

Comment: Write functions that solve one thing at a time.

Comment: `I have tried to get rid of the 2 dimensional array for this method, ExtractData and replace it with using a list` How is your 2-dim array? What is the data in your file? which data do you want to exctract? How should your output list be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a variable number of events, and each event has 5 "lines" of text that you wish to store separately?  Create a class to represent each Events data, and create a list of them.

```
public class EventData {
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Line4 { get; set; }
    public string Line5 { get; set; }
}

...

var results = new List<EventData>();

// loop through lines in file
 while ( objInput.Peek() > -1 &&
    m_intNumberOfEvents < 10 )
 {
    intFileDay = Int32.Parse( strLine ); // extract day

    // if event scheduled for specified day,
    // store information
    if ( intFileDay == intChosenDay )
    {
        var foo = new EventData();

        foo.Line1 = strLine;
        foo.Line2 = objInput.ReadLine();
        foo.Line3 = objInput.ReadLine();
        foo.Line4 = objInput.ReadLine();
        foo.Line5 = objInput.ReadLine();

        results.Add(foo);

        m_intNumberOfEvents++;
    }
    else
    {
       // skip to next event in file
       for ( intLineNumbers = 0; intLineNumbers <= 3;
          intLineNumbers++ )
          strLine = objInput.ReadLine();
    }

    // read day of next event in file
    strLine = objInput.ReadLine();

 } // end while
```

Comment: Wow, just like that...if you take a look at my previous posts. You can see how much I struggled. Thank you for your help Dylan.

Answer (score 0):

Have to repeat what Dylan Smith said; make a class.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but it looks like you want an array of events that happen daily.  If so then a class really makes the most sense.  The class will not only store those strings, but you can also have more and more easily managed data (say the time of day an event will occur).

Really if you see yourself getting into an issue like this where you want more than just one variable to hold some information about something, make a class or a struct.  You'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is no point of defining a new class in this case. All of your fields are strings and you don't have methods or properties in the class. It is simply an array of strings. Use:

```
var results = new List<string[]>(); 
...
var lines = new string[5];

lines[0] = strLine;
lines[1] = objInput.ReadLine();
lines[2] = objInput.ReadLine();
lines[3] = objInput.ReadLine();
lines[4] = objInput.ReadLine();

results.Add(lines);
```